# port 8035 is running on 0.0.0.0:8035 but can't access it with the server ip address at Digital ocean

Tags: server, port, digital-ocean

I have configured and run my application on port 8035.

It's showing running in localhost as local address, 0.0.0.0:8035

I also make it as sudo ufw allow 8035/tcp

I am using ubuntu at the Digital ocean cloud server

But I can't access it from the internet with my server IP address.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Go to Networking -> Create Firewall

and set INBOUND Rule to allow 8035